# Change of OVH Primary IPV4 Address

Tags: ipv4

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the Primary IPV4 address of an OVH Dedicated Server (Ubuntu 20.04) to a Failover IPV4 attached to the server? I am not wanting to configure/attach the failover IP, but rather make it the actual default/primary IP of the server.

Moreover, if I could just make it so all outbound traffic uses the failover instead of the main IP attached to the server, that would also be very useful.

Comment: Some informations may be useful : how many network interfaces ? How many distinct address range (said otherwise, have you got one or two gateway addresses). Linux doesn’t consider an address more important than an other, but your default address route may change how the returned packets are sent.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I have 1 network interface currently active, "enp1s0f0", which is using OVH dhcp with mcaddress match, and I have 4 IPs, plus he main server IP.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have only one interface, the server will respond to any IP address it is bounded and use the only interface to reply. No one IP is really the main/default address. If you want your client to use one of the « secondary » addresses as a default, you have to set it in your DNS.

Secondary addresses are interesting if you want to define different virtual servers (typically containers) and give each virtual server a different address. Apache can also make use of IP addresses and serve some pages only on a given address. In this case, we can consider the primary to be used by the host and secondaries addresses assigned to virtual server, but it is just a convention. You have to read the documentation of each daemon to know how to restrict them to one given address (`man sshd_config` and seek ListenAddress for `ssh`).